# "the command is not available because no document is open" - MS Word 2010 VBA Error from Lotus Notes

Tags: vba, ms-word, lotus-notes

I have some VBA code which, executing within Lotus Notes 8.5.2, creates a MS Word Document based on a MS Word 2003 template. This works fine for me with Word 2003, 2007 and 2010. One customer however with MS Word 2010 gets the error `MS Word: the command is not available because no document is open` at the line:

```
Set wdObject = createObject("word.Application")
wdObject.Documents.Add( wordpath &  "\" & docname )
wdObject.ActiveDocument.Builtindocumentproperties(wdPropertyTitle) = sTemplateName
```

Why would this error occur for one user with Word 2010 and not for me? She has Windows 7, Folder Redirection is not configured.

Comment: Please ensure that the path exists `wordpath &  "\" & docname`

Comment: yes, the path and docname are correct. wordpath is a nemly created folder - "C:\TempWord" and doc name is the name of the new (created through this code) MS Word document.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to code it like this:

```
    On Error Goto CreateNewInstance
    Set msWord = GetObject("", "Word.Application")
Done:
    Set CreateMSWordDocument = msWord
    Exit Function
CreateNewInstance:
    Print "Loading Microsoft Word.... Please Wait...."
    Err = 0
    Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Print "Microsoft Word Loaded"
    Resume Done
```

Comment: Thanks but the error occurs at wdObject.ActiveDocument.Builtindocumentproperties(wdPropertyTitle) = sTemplateName the object is created without any problem

Comment: This code works fine for another user with a seemingly identical configuration

Comment: yes, a new word document is created using a template. No existing word document is open, the whole idea is to create a new Word document (based on a .dot template).